# Is there a difference between !== and != in PHP?

Tags: php, comparison, operators

Is there a difference between `!==` and `!=` in PHP?

Comment: Very commonly duplicated question, depending on how you search for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-and-identity-comparison-operators-differ

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `!=` operator compares value, while the `!==` operator compares type as well.

That means this:

```
var_dump(5!="5"); // bool(false)
var_dump(5!=="5"); // bool(true), because "5" and 5 are of different types
```

Comment: null!="null" is not false, wrong example. Also echo prints 1 for bool(true) and nothing for bool(false). The actual output of the code snippet is 11.

Comment: @VolkerK — I don't have a PHP interpreter in front of me, but hopefully this is a more accurate example.  :-)

Comment: My mistake. Thanks for the edit, Ben Blank. Hopefully the original poster didn't get confused.

Comment: `==` also treats type a little differently from `===` - for instance, numeric strings ("5", "05") are compared as numbers, and associative arrays in different orders can still be equal.  I would describe `===` as "exactly the same", rather than "equal value and type".

Answer (score 8):

`!=` is the inverse of the `==` operator, which checks equality across types

`!==` is the inverse of the `===` operator, which checks equality only for things of the same type.

Answer (score 4):

`!=` is for "not equal", while `!==` is for "not identical".  For example:

```
'1' != 1   # evaluates to false, because '1' equals 1
'1' !== 1  # evaluates to true, because '1' is of a different type than 1
```

Answer (score 3):

!== checks type as well as value, != only checks value

```
$num =  5

if ($num == "5") // true, since both contain 5
if ($num === "5") // false, since "5" is not the same type as 5, (string vs int)
```

Answer (score 2):

=== is called the Identity Operator.  And is discussed in length in other question's responses.

Others' responses here are also correct.

Answer (score 2):

Operator `!=` returns true, if its two operands have different values.

Operator `!==` returns true, if its two operands have different values or they are of different types.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

See the [PHP type comparison tables](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) on what values are equal (`==`) and what identical (`===`).