# What does !== comparison operator in PHP mean?

Tags: php, comparison, operators

I saw

```
if($output !== false){
}
```

It's an exclamation mark with two equals signs.

It almost works like not equal. Does it has any extra significance?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-and-identity-comparison-operators-differ

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139154/is-there-a-difference-between-and-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

They are the strict equality operators ( ===, !==) , the two operands must have the same type and value in order the result to be true.

For example:

```
var_dump(0 == "0"); //  true
var_dump("1" == "01"); //  true
var_dump("1" == true); //  true

var_dump(0 === "0"); //  false
var_dump("1" === "01"); //  false
var_dump("1" === true); //  false
```

More information:

- [PHP Comparison Operators](http://php.net/ternary)

Answer (score 5):

PHP’s === Operator enables you to compare or test variables for both equality and type.

So !== is (not ===)

Answer (score 5):

`!==` checks the type of the variable as well as the value.  So for example,

```
$a = 1;
$b = '1';
if ($a != $b) echo 'hello';
if ($a !== $b) echo 'world';
```

will output just 'world', as `$a` is an integer and `$b` is a string.

You should check out the manual page on [PHP operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), it's got some good explanations.

Answer (score 3):

See this question: [How do the equality (==) and identity (===) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-and-identity-comparison-operators-differ).

'!==' is the strict version of not equal. I.e. it will also check type.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it also checks that the two values are the same type. If $output is 0, then  !== will return false, because they are not both numbers or booleans.