# what is the difference between '!= 'and '!== '

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a difference between !== and != in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139154/is-there-a-difference-between-and-in-php)
>   [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

In some cases when checking for not equal, I saw using  `!=`  and in some places i saw `!==`. Is there any difference in that?

Example:

```
var x = 10;   

if (x != 10) {   
    //...
}
```

and

```
if (x !== 10) {    
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`==` compares only the value and converts between types to find an equality, `===` compares the types as well.

Answer (score 3):

- `==` means equal
- `===` means identical

`1` is equal to `"1"`, but not identical, because `1` is an integer and `"1"` is a string.

Answer (score 3):

They are different in terms of strictness of comparison. `!==` compares variable types in addition to values.

Answer (score 2):

!== will also check the type (int, string, etc.) while != doesn't.

For more information, see [the PHP comparison operator documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 2):

The !== is strict not equal: [Difference between == and === in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that
`==` (and `!=`) compare only the value, 
`===` (and `!==`) compare the value and the type.

For example
`"1" == 1` returns `true`
`"1" === 1` returns `false`, because one is a string and the other is an integer

Hope this helps. Cheers