# Difference between !== and !=

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)
>   [Javascript operator !==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889260/javascript-operator)

What's the difference between `!=` and `!==`?

Can you give me an example where using `!=` gives another result than using `!==`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559358/what-is-the-difference-between-and?rq=1 should help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
alert(1 != true);
alert(1 !== true);
```

The first one is false, the second true.

- `!=` accept 1 as equals of true, null as equals of false and some others (because the values are automatically casted when being compared).
- `!==` accept only "real" equalities (i.e. compares both the value and the type).

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/CKh9R/)

Comment: That's not really an answer though.

Comment: I clicked by accident.. sorry.

Comment: @Diego Then, if I am comparing variables (of which I don't know the value), should I always use `!==`?

Comment: It depends the case. If you have a boolean variable its actually the same. If you have an integer you should use `!==` to compare it with integers or `!=` to "auto cast it" to boolean

Comment: `null` never equals `false` in an equality comparison.

Comment: @amnotiam You are actually right `(null == false)` is `false`. I got confused because `(null)` (if evaluated as boolean) is `false` and `(!null)` `true`.