# Problem to send two boolean with ajax and setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have two function which should each send either 0 or 1 on a php page with ajax.
when pressing a key on the keyboard, the function that sends 1 starts and the one that sends 0 must start three seconds later with a setTimeout ().
The problem is that the second function doesn't send.
I send you the party of the corresponding code.
Thanking you in advance for your help, and please forgive my not very nice English to read ^^'

My code :

```
function typing() {
  var typingBool = 1
  if (typingBool != "") {
    let donneee = {}
    donneee["typingBool"] = typingBool
    let donneeeJson = JSON.stringify(donneee)
    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajax/typing.php")
    xmlhttp.send(donneeeJson)
  }
}

function typing2() {
  var typingBool = 0
  if (typingBool != "") {
    let donneee = {}
    donneee["typingBool"] = typingBool
    let donneeeJson = JSON.stringify(donneee)
    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajax/typing.php")
    xmlhttp.send(donneeeJson)
  }
}

var typingText = document.getElementById('texte');
typingText.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
  typing();
  setTimeout(function() {
    typing2()
  }, 3000);
})
```

Comment: your typing2 func doesnt make much sense, whats the purpose of the typingBool var and the if?

Comment: `0 != ""`  <-- this returns `false`, because `0` is falsy, and `""` is falsy, so your `if` does not pass. Use `!==` to perform a strict check. But yes, your code seems a little verbose, it could be shortened quite a bit

Comment: What's the point of doing `if` immediately after assigning the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is the [difference between `!=` & `!==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960603/difference-between-and):

```js
if (0 !=  "") { console.log("Won't be displayed"); }
if (0 !== "") { console.log("Will be displayed");  }
```

That being said, your code could be shortened a bit, this should work:

```
function typing(typingBool){
  let donneeeJson = JSON.stringify({ typingBool: typingBool });
  let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajax/typing.php");
  xmlhttp.send(donneeeJson);
}

var typingText = document.getElementById('texte');
typingText.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
  typing(1);
  setTimeout(function(){ typing(0); }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: it works, thank you very much for your help, i appreciate it ! :)