# What may go wrong if I don't use === or !== in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, comparison, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php == vs === operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589549/php-vs-operator)
>   [Is there a difference between !== and != in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139154/is-there-a-difference-between-and-in-php)

In PHP, the condition of the `if` command contains operator `===` and `!==`.

I never use them. So I wonder when will we actually need to call them?

E.g.

```
if (FALSE !=  someMethod() ) {
}

if (FALSE !== someMethod() ) {
}
```

What may go wrong with the 1st `if`?

Comment: exact duplicate of the 1000s of the kind

Comment: Before asking, you should try to spend some time on google

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel When you vote close you can nominate one of the '1000's.

Comment: @NamGVU Did my answer help you?

Comment: @Paulpro No, sorry it's not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
0 == '' == null == false == array()
```

If you need to know the difference between two of these, you need ===.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )

strpos('apple', 'a') == 0

strpos('apple', 'b') == false
```

Without a === you won't know if 'apple' has 'a' in the first position or if it doesn't exist.

Comment: For strpos sample, I don't think comparing with boolean value is the right usage of this method.

Comment: Though, your statement on `0`, `null`, `''`, `false`, and `array()` is the excellent point-out for me. Great thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Take an example like this:

```
$str = '*Hello*World*';
if (FALSE != strpos($str, '*')){
    // Echo if string has an '*' in it!
    echo $str;
}
```

This won't work, because [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns the index of the first match. In this case it returns 0. `FALSE == 0`, but `FALSE !== 0`.

Comment: I think your good scenario describe a wrong usage of `strpos` function - the meaning of the returned integer value SHOULD NOT be used as boolean at all. And that's not persuade enough for me to use !== there indeed.

Comment: @NamGVU `strpos` returns a boolean if there is no match. It can also return `0` if the match is at the very beginning of the string. If you use `!=` you can't tell whether it returned `0` or `false`, but if you use `!==` you can tell the difference between a match at the beginning of a string or no match at all.

Comment: @NamGVU Also see the warning in the section about the return values in the PHP manual page for [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: Agree. My bad not reading the manual carefully. Thanks a lot for helping me to know that!

Comment: After all, this leads to PHP's design for such `strpos` function - I mean if PHP considers FALSE and 0 to be "the same" when compared, then they should make strpos to be the traditional way as other languages do e.g. C++, Java, C# ect.

Comment: @NamGVU Yeah, PHP is a very weird language in many different ways.

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses loose comparison when you use `==` and `!=' instead of`===`and '!==`. Loose comparison means, that types are compared on 'similarity'. To get an overview of how types compare, look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: Would be lovely if you would bring up some samples. Thanks