# Should I use != null and !== null in php?

Tags: php

I was trying to use isset but it said that I have to use !== null instead. Should I use != null or !== null. What is the difference?

Comment: That is the wrong duplicate.  For the record, you should use the identical operator (`===` or `!==`) whenever possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139154/is-there-a-difference-between-and-in-php @EduGrando