# how to compare a variable with multiple values

Tags: php

Hello everyone I would like to be able to compare the country variable with country values ​​and if the country variable is not in my list display an error
I have a code but it does not work

```
else if($country  <> "Belgique")or ($country   <> "Luxembourg") or ($country   <> "France")or($country   <> "Pays-bas")
 {echo "The country variable is not in the list "; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have a fairly straight-forward syntax error: the syntax of an `if` statement is `if ( condition )` Note those parentheses - they're part of the if statement itself, not the condition. When you write this:

```
if ( $country <> "Belgique" )
```

The condition is this:

```
$country <> "Belgique"
```

So if you want the condition to be this:

```
($country <> "Belgique") or ($country <> "Luxembourg") or ($country <> "France") or ($country <> "Pays-bas")
```

Then you have to put *the whole thing* inside the parentheses of the if statement:

```
if ( ($country <> "Belgique") or ($country <> "Luxembourg") or ($country <> "France") or ($country <> "Pays-bas") )
```

---

Secondly, you have made a common mistake in translating English (or whatever your first language is) into formal logic: it's tempting to assume that `($country <> "Belgique") or ($country <> "Luxembourg")` means "$country is neither Belgique nor Luxembourg", but it actually means "if $country is not Belgique then evaluate to true; also, if $country is not Luxembourg then evaluate to true".

If you provide "Luxembourg", the first part is true; if you provide "Belgique", the second part is true; in fact, since no value of `$country` is both Belgique and Luxembourg at once, the result is always true!

What you actually wanted to say was "if $country is not Belgique *and also* $country is not Luxembourg, then evaluate to true": `($country <> "Belgique") and ($country <> "Luxembourg")`

So:

```
if ( ($country <> "Belgique") and ($country <> "Luxembourg") and ($country <> "France") and ($country <> "Pays-bas") )
```

(This fact that `not ( A or B )` is equivalent to `( not A ) and ( not B )` is known as [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).)

---

As a side note, in PHP, `and` and `or` are not quite the same as `&&` and `||`. See stackoverflow.com/questions/4502092/php-and-or-keywords

Although it doesn't make any difference in this case, because you've grouped things neatly with parentheses, `&&` and `||` are more often the operators you want, giving:

```
if ( ($country <> "Belgique") && ($country <> "Luxembourg") && ($country <> "France") && ($country <> "Pays-bas") )
```

`<>` *is* identical in meaning to `!=`, but there is also the stricter `!==`, see [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp) and [Is there a difference between !== and != in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139154/is-there-a-difference-between-and-in-php)

So you might actually want this:

```
if ( ($country !== "Belgique") && ($country !== "Luxembourg") && ($country !== "France") && ($country !== "Pays-bas") )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the explanations it works wonderfully
Again a thousand thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use in_array function instead of many if else.

```
$country_list = array("Belgique", "Luxembourg", "France", "Pays-bas");
if(!in_array($country, $country_list)) {
   echo "The country variable is not in the list";
}
```